# Expose Multiple classes through single WCF OperationContract

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two(there will be more) C# classes that implement this interface:

```
public class Enumerador 
{        
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Descripcion{ get; set; }        
}

public interface IEnumerador
{
    List<Enumerador> Enumerar(string sFilter="");
}
```

Then i use this interface on my classes like this:

```
public class VendedoresRepository : IEnumerador
{
    public List<Enumerador> Enumerar(string sFilter = "")        
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {
            return (from vnd in context.Vendedores.Where(f => f.Activo == true).OrderBy(o => o.Nombre)
                    select new Enumerador { ID = vnd.ID_Vendedor, Descripcion = vnd.Nombre }).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class ANX_FormasPagoRepository : IEnumerador
{
    public List<Enumerador> Enumerar(string sFilter = "")
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {                               
            return (from fp in context.ANX_FormasPago.OrderBy(o => o.FormaPago)
                    select new Enumerador { ID = fp.ID_FormaPago, Descripcion = fp.FormaPago }).ToList();
        }
    }
}

and so on...
```

so all my classes have a method that returns a Enumerador object.

**So my questions are:**

1) How can i have a single OperationContract to exposes all my classes?

2) How can my client code ask WCF service to return a Enumarador Object from a specific class?

Thanks!

Comment: Your contract is plausible, you cannot have a contract represent multiple diverse business entities

Comment: thanks @saravanan for you comment. If all the classes are exposing the same object class (Enumarador in this case) that means that the type of data returned by the service is fixed. Why cannot represent diverse entities?

Comment: you should devise separate services for your business entities like `NX_FormasPago` and `vendores` because they are separate entities, your business logic will vary and your service consumers should be able to clearly distinguish the business services they wish to invoke. we cannot have our clients do some preparation before calling our services,